# Give Azure web service access to existing remote SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to make a web page that is going to make an API call to query data in our existing remote SQL Server. When I am testing it now, my code can access the database using windows authentication, but when I deploy this web page on Azure, will my code be able to still access the remote SQL Server using windows authentication? If not, what do I need to do in order for my web page to query the data in the existing remote SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid Connections is both a service in Azure and a feature in Azure App Service. As a service, it has uses and capabilities beyond those that are used in App Service. To learn more about Hybrid Connections and their usage outside App Service, see Azure Relay Hybrid Connections.

Within App Service, Hybrid Connections can be used to access application resources in other networks. It provides access from your app to an application endpoint. It does not enable an alternate capability to access your application. As used in App Service, each Hybrid Connection correlates to a single TCP host and port combination. This means that the Hybrid Connection endpoint can be on any operating system and any application, provided you are accessing a TCP listening port. The Hybrid Connections feature does not know or care what the application protocol is, or what you are accessing. It is simply providing network access.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections